# Exporting a specific sheet with Google Spreadsheet's Direct Download URL to Dropbox folder

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, http-get

I have a spreadsheet names 'spreadsheet' and it has three sheets named 'a','b', and 'c' respectively. I currently published this spreadsheet with this url format

```
<!-- This script uses the super simple Dropbox Drop-In API -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="ex4mpl3K3y"></script>

<!-- This anchor establishes the dropbox button which determines the file to download to your dropbox folder. --> 

<a href="https://docs.google.com/a/account/spreadsheets/d/r4Nd0MSpR34d5h33t/export?format=csv&id=r4Nd0MSpR34d5h33t" data-filename="file-name.csv" class="dropbox-saver"></a>
```

This url format allows anyone to download a csv version of the file, but it downloads sheets a,b, and c. How would I modify this url to download only sheet b or sheet c?

Comment: AFAIK, you wouldn't modify your URL, you would create a new Google Apps Script that copy the specified sheet and downloads to the user, using the Publish WebApp service.

Comment: Thanks @Kriggs ! I actually found out what the url needs to be. There are four variables: account,spreadsheetId,sheetId, and format. I'm writing out a small task that will get the dynamically get these variables via a macro, and I'll be posting that answer.

Answer (score 1):

## How to Export Google Spreadsheet to Dropbox

---

### Setting up Dropbox

1. Create a Dropbox account at www.dropbox.com
2. Create a Dropbox app using the API Console at 
   https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps make sure to give it a **Drop-ins permission type**.
3. In the App Console tab, go to your new app's settings and add the following domains

> docs.google.com ||
>   127.0.0.1 ||
>   localhost ||
>   googleusercontent.com

4. Note the app key
5. Add this script to use [the Dropbox Drop-in API's Saver method](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/saver): `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="YOURAPPKEYRECEIVEDFROMAPICONSOLE"></script>`

---

### Setting up Google Spreadsheet

1. [Set up a google account](https://accounts.google.com/signup)
2. [Create a spreadsheet](https://www.google.com/sheets)
3. [Securely publish the sheet to the web](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?hl=en)
4. On the spreadsheet toolbar go to `Tools` > `Script Editor`. This will open a new window where you will see an empty javascript file called `code.gs`
5. Add one of the scripts below to your `code.js`
6. The `sheetId` is the random series of characters that follow the /d/ in the url. The `gid` can by found by going to the `publish sheet to the web` option and selecting a specific sheet to publish, copying the url given, and finding the value inside the http query parameter labeled `&gid=`

---

### Functional Macro Magic

The code you will see is a very simple script that adds a menu option to your spreadsheet

```
    function onOpen() {
          var menuItems = [
            {name: 'Dropbox', functionName: 'dropbox'}
          ];
          SpreadsheetApp.getActive().addMenu('The Make Life Easy Button', menuItems);
    }
    function dropbox(){

     var dropboxKey = 'string';
     var sheetid = 'string';
     var gid = 'string';
     var fileName = 'string';
     var testResults = '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="'+ dropboxKey +'"></script>';
  testResults += '<h2>Store Content Sheet</h2><a href="https://docs.google.com/a/' + account + '/spreadsheets/d/' + sheetid + '/pub?gid=' + gid + '&single=true&output=csv" data-filename="' + fileName + '" class="dropbox-saver"></a>'; 

    // Show a dialog with the test results.
       var htmlApp = HtmlService
         .createHtmlOutput(testResults)
         .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
         .setTitle('Test Results')
         .setWidth(600)
         .setHeight(400);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(htmlApp);
    }
```

---

### Note to Future Readers

You will need to give permission to both google script and dropbox.

Please make sure to leave comments on any steps that need further clarification, and I will make sure to fill in the gaps. If content is out-of-date, leaving comments on updated material would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hey Joseph! This is a great write up, I am looking for something very similar but I need to put it on a trigger. Basically every hour or so, upload/overwrite the same sheet to Dropbox. Do you think this is possible? I started to go down the path of trying to extract a sheet as a CSV file, then programatically upload it to Dropbox with this endpoint 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload' but I got stuck with how to actually convert/provide the sheet as a csv file. This seems like an easier approach and was wondering if it could work without any manual intervention.